# Xcodeproj create Today Extension (widget) scheme

Tags: ios, ruby, today-extension, xcodeproj

Here is the code to create a target scheme.

```
scheme = Xcodeproj::XCScheme.new
scheme.add_build_target(target)
scheme.set_launch_target(target)
scheme.save_as(xcode_proj_dir, name)
```

How to create a scheme for Today Extension?

There are some differences: Today Extension scheme locates in `xcuserdata` instead of `xcshareddata` and `Executable` should be `Ask on Launch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I did it like this:

```
scheme = Xcodeproj::XCScheme.new
scheme.add_build_target(target)
scheme.build_action.add_entry(Xcodeproj::XCScheme::BuildAction::Entry.new(app_target))
scheme.test_action.add_macro_expansion(Xcodeproj::XCScheme::MacroExpansion.new(target))
scheme.launch_action.launch_automatically_substyle = "2"
scheme.profile_action.buildable_product_runnable = Xcodeproj::XCScheme::BuildableProductRunnable.new(app_target, 0)
scheme.save_as(xcode_proj_dir, widget_name)
```